# ¿Se puede agregar un botón borrar por cada elemento option en un drop down list?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo el siguiente select cuyas opciones son generadas automáticamente por angular:

```
<select class="form-control p-0">
 <option>--Select Default Filter Profile--</option>
 <option *ngFor="let filter of filterProfiles" value ={{filter.id}}>{{filter.profileName}}</option>
</select>
```

Me gustaría agregar un botón para borrar un elemento inline por cada option que a su vez desencadene la ejecución de una función de angular que reciba el id y se encargue del borrado.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Es necesario agregar el boton ?, lo que podrias hacer es que cada que seleccionen la opcion le preguntes si desea eliminar esa opcion del campo

Comment: Intentare agregar una en las próximas horas.

Comment: Hola lo único que encontré cuando investigue fue esto no se si te sirva , https://picodotdev.github.io/blog-bitix/2016/10/anadir-botones-selectores-de-opciones-a-select-multiple-de-bootsrap-select/ , creo que no se pueden agregar botones en los drop, lo que podrias hacer es validar si selecciona la opcion y preguntar si desea eliminar esa opcion del drpo

Answer (score 0):

Con un `<select>` no puedes, tendrías que crearte tu propio componente y a punta de estilos CSS hacer que parezca un select (que no es muy dificil la verdad), o buscar algún componente en la web donde haga algo parecido, pero con el propio de HTML no puedes.